# Many to Many relationships dont sync AWS Amplify

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, flutter, dart, aws-amplify

I'm using VSCode, flutter, dart, iOS simulator

I followed this tutorial to make the TODO app: https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/setup/q/integration/flutter/#set-up-frontend

All worked well. I can see mutations appearing in content tab in amplify studio.

When I add a many to many relationship (an arbitrary one, add a Foo model and relate it to the Todo model), and no other changes, I no longer see the mutations appearing in content tab in amplify studio. It works locally, and I don't see any errors. It just doesn't seem to sync to the cloud

Is this expected?